# Do stealth/invisibility effects hide me from invading Guardians?

Tags: destiny-2

So apparently, when you invade the other team in Gambit/Prime, you essentially get wallhacks for the duration you're invading.

What I'm curious about, since I can't seem to tell, is whether or not my stealth invisibility effects hide my giant red aura when I'm invading, and whether or not it hides my red aura when an opposing Guardian has invaded us.

Comment: For clarification, I am assuming you mean the invader having a red aura? Because the team who's being invaded has their names above the guardian displayed for the invader, but they don't have the red glowing aura, only the invader does. Crouching without moving does hide names and dots on the minimap from the invader too.

Comment: @n_plum So when an enemy guardian invades, you can't see your red glow, but to the invader, they can see your position at all times (and when you do show up in their line of sight, you do glow red)

Comment: You do get that like, red outline, but it's not the same "aura" that the invader has with the red and white mist around them too. I think that's what I'm clarifying a difference of

Comment: On my graphic settings Invaders look just like enemy guardians when I invade